# Copy elements from one array into another

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to copy some elements from one array to newly created one.

I create an array **arr**, filter elements from another array **str** and if its elements match `checkPalin` condition I want to add them into **arr**, but I struggle to do so, my IDE underscores **arr** array.

```
String [] arr;
        for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
            if(checkPalin(str[i])==true){
                arr[i] = str[i];
            }
        }
        return arr;
```

Comment: per your posted code, `arr` is and remains null, and so `arr[i]` should throw a NPE. Best to initialize it first, for example, something like: `arr = new String[str.length];`

Comment: Side note, this: `if(checkPalin(str[i])==true){` is better written as `if (checkPalin(str[i])) {`

Comment: You forgot to initialize variable `arr` that's why IDE is hightlighting line `arr[i] = str[i];` since variable `arr == null`.

Your code should looks like this:
```java
String[] arr = new String[str.length];
```